# How do I solve Google Maps API HTTP 400 Error?

Tags: python, network-analysis

I am attempting to caclulate driving times from a list of tuples of starting points to each tuple in a destination list. The following code yielded an HTTPError: HTTP Error: 400

```
import googlemaps
code = 'xxx'
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key = code)
groceryLocations = [(lat, lon) for lat, lon in zip(grocery['SnapY'],
                                               grocery['SnapX'])]
startingPoints = [(float(lat), float(lon)) for lat, lon in zip(zipCentroid['INTPTLAT20'],
                                             zipCentroid['INTPTLON20'])]
origins = startingPoints
destinations = groceryLocations
now = datetime.now()
dist_matrix = gmaps.distance_matrix(origins, destinations, mode='driving', departure_time=now)
```

Comment: How many points are in each list?